# Why does Visual Studio debug mode only recognize https address?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to reconstruct three versions (debug/test/production) of a large solution, which incorporates 120 different projects, including one web site. The differences between the versions are minor.

I've got all three versions reconstructed and building successfully. When I launch each with the F5 local debug, it goes searching for the web site on the developer version of IIS. In two of the versions, it succeeds and pulls up the web site normally. In the third, it says it can't find the web site, even though the address in the browser reads exactly what it should, including the port number (which matches the port number given on the info page for the web site in Visual Studio).

The kicker is this: when I enable SSL for this third version, after launching the solution via F5, it still won't find the web site -- until I replace the port number with the SSL port number, and the "http" with "https". Then it loads the web site.

Does anyone know what can make Visual Studio 2012 behave like this, and how I can make the behavior of the third solution match the other two?

Comment: can you describe what you mean by these versions? Are they separate visual studio solutions (.sln) altogether or are they the same vs solution but with different solution configurations as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wx0123s5.aspx)?

Comment: They're separate .sln's.

Comment: Do you know whether the websites are actually Web Application Projects or Web Site Projects?  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Comment: The websites have no .caproj or .vbproj files, so I guess that makes them web site projects.

Comment: If you select the project in Solution Explorer, right click to access the properties window, what do the fields in the property pane show?

Comment: Anonynmous Authentication: Enabled; Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated; SSL Enabled: True; SSL URL: https://localhost:44300/; URL http://localhost:54457; Windows Authentication: Disabled; Full Path:I:\TFS\WebAll\Prod\WebSite; Opened URL: http://localhost:54457/